# Assign a value to a Character String..?

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

Here's my problem.. I have two arrays: one has the total marks of students and another is a character string. So, I want the computer to assign a letter grade to the character string when the array with the total marks is in within a range..

Here's what a came up with but it won't compile and I don't have anything else in mind:

Comment: use `strcpy` like this `strcpy(grade[i], "A+");`

Comment: or `strncpy` for extra safety like this `strncpy(grade[i], "A+", MAX_LETTER_SIZE);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I tried and it only works for A+, then when I print it everything looks funny

Comment: i think you should  remove `break;`

Comment: I'm going to try it.. I just thought about that

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I tried and it works better than before but the only problem I notice is that when I have to print 3 same letters, one after the other, the first one won't print.. any ideas?

Comment: Please show me the code(edit post) to reproduce.

Comment: `if (total[i]>=80 && total[i]<=89) {` change to `else if (total[i]>=80) {`. (Other likewise) because E.g `89.6` fall into the gap.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Sure! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sprintf(grade[i], "%s", "A+");
```

Comment: Why not just use `strcpy`?

Answer (score -1):

What is the compilation error message?

I'll assume you've allocated resources properly. Even if you have and everything is compiling this line of code will cause an array bounds bug (as you've defined things):

grade[i][MAX_LETTER_SIZE]

should be:

sprintf(grade[i], "A+");

I really would send arrays as pointers. It is much cleaner and more efficient. You might also wish to create an LUT that maps scores to grades. This will reduce the amount of code you need to write. Otherwise you'll require a series of if statements rather than an inner loop with a single if statement. Good luck.